# Odd problem with loop

Tags: php

I have the following loop, which works fine if i<1 but gives me the the following error if i<2. I cannot for the life of me figure out what it is.

I get this error: Query failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE 1244790000 - datecreated >= 432000' at line 1 Actual query:

And here is the loop: ( I apologize for the mess...Only been programming for a few months and have not adopted OOP yet :[ ... )

```
        for($i=0;$i<2;$i++) {
    $row=mysql_fetch_assoc($displaylistings);

    // Check to what store this listing belongs to
    $nordstromtest=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM nordstromlisting WHERE ShopperID = '$ShopperID'");
    $nordstromstore=mysql_fetch_assoc($nordstromtest);
    if ($row == $nordstromstore) {
        $storename = "Nordstrom Listing: ";
        $storetbl = "nordstromlisting";
    }

    $saksfifthavenuetest=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM saksfifthavenuelisting WHERE ShopperID = '$ShopperID'");
    $saksfifthavenuestore=mysql_fetch_assoc($saksfifthavenuetest);
    if ($row == $saksfifthavenuestore) {
        $storename = "Sak's Fifth Avenue Listing: ";
        $storetbl = "saksfifthavenuelisting";
    }

    $neimanmarcustest=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM neimanmarcuslisting WHERE ShopperID = '$ShopperID'");
    $neimanmarcusstore=mysql_fetch_assoc($neimanmarcustest);
    if ($row == $neimanmarcusstore) {
        $storename = "Neiman Marcus Listing: ";
        $storetbl = "neimanmarcuslisting";
    }

    $guesstest=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM guesslisting WHERE ShopperID = '$ShopperID'");
    $guessstore=mysql_fetch_assoc($guesstest);
    if ($row == $guessstore) {
        $storename = "GUESS Listing: ";
        $storetbl = "guesslisting";
    }

    $americaneagletest=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM americaneaglelisting WHERE ShopperID = '$ShopperID'");
    $americaneaglestore=mysql_fetch_assoc($americaneagletest);
    if ($row == $americaneaglestore) {
        $storename = "American Eagle Listing: ";
        $storetbl = "americaneaglelisting";
    }

    $gnctest=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM gnclisting WHERE ShopperID = '$ShopperID'");
    $gncstore=mysql_fetch_assoc($gnctest);
    if ($row == $gncstore) {
        $storename = "GNC Listing: ";
        $storetbl = "gnclisting";
    }

    $footlockertest=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM footlockerlisting WHERE ShopperID = '$ShopperID'");
    $footlockerstore=mysql_fetch_assoc($footlockertest);
    if ($row == $footlockerstore) {
        $storename = "Foot Locker Listing: ";
        $storetbl = "footlockerlisting";
    }

    $bananarepublictest=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM bananarepubliclisting WHERE ShopperID = '$ShopperID'");
    $bananarepublicstore=mysql_fetch_assoc($bananarepublictest);
    if ($row == $bananarepublicstore) {
        $storename = "Banana Republic Listing: ";
        $storetbl = "bananarepubliclisting";
    }

    $urbanoutfitterstest=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM urbanoutfitterslisting WHERE ShopperID = '$ShopperID'");
    $urbanoutfittersstore=mysql_fetch_assoc($urbanoutfitterstest);
    if ($row == $urbanoutfittersstore) {
        $storename = "Urban Outfitters Listing: ";
        $storetbl = "urbanoutfitterslisting";
    }

    //Delete old listings (test with minutes...)

    $timenow = date("Y-m-d");
    $time = strtotime($timenow);
    $storehistory = str_ireplace("listing","history","$storetbl");
    $movetohistory = mysql_query("INSERT INTO $storehistory SELECT * FROM $storetbl WHERE $time - datecreated >= 432000");
    $deltefromlisting = mysql_query("DELETE FROM $storetbl WHERE $time - datecreated >= 432000") or die ("Query failed: " . mysql_error() . " Actual query: " . $query);

    //Item link modifactions
    if ($row['link'] != null) {
        $shortlink = substr($row['link'],0,30);
        $shortlink .= '...';
    }


    if ($row['itemsize'] != null ) {
        $mensshirt = $row['itemsize'];
    }

    if ($row['waistsize'] != 0) {
        $waistsize = $row['waistsize'];
        $w = 'Waist';
    }

    if ($row['lengthsize'] != 0) {
        $lengthsize = $row['lengthsize'];
        $l = 'Length';
    }

    if ($row['ladystopsize'] != null) {
        $ladystopsize = $row['ladystopsize'];
    }

    if ($row['ladysdresssize'] != 0) {
        $ladysdresssize = $row['ladysdresssize'];
    }

    if ($row['ladysbottomsize'] != 0) {
        $ladysbottomsize = $row['ladysbottomsize'];
    }

    if ($row['shoesize'] != 0) {
        $shoesize = $row['shoesize'];
    }

    echo "<div id='listings2'><div id='storenametab'><b><span class='storename'>$storename</span></b></div><br /><br />";
    echo "<span id='orderdetails'>Item Number : $row[itemnum] <br />";
    echo "Discount Price: $$row[DiscountedPrice] <br />";
    echo "Item Type : $row[itemtype]<br />";
    echo "Item Size :
    $mensshirt 
    $waistsize $w 
    $lengthsize $l 
    $ladystopsize 
    $ladysdresssize 
    $ladysbottomsize 
    $shoesize
    <br />";
    echo "Item Color: $row[itemcolor] <br />";

    if ($row['link'] != null) {
    echo "Item URL: <a href='$row[link]' target='_blank'>$shortlink</a><br />";
    }
```

//STATUS

```
    if ($row['VillainID'] == 0)
        echo "Status: Unclaimed <br />";

    else {

        $VillainPaypalEmail = mysql_query("SELECT PaypalEmail FROM villains WHERE VillainID = '$row[VillainID]'");
        $fetchVillain = mysql_fetch_assoc($VillainPaypalEmail);
        $VillainPaypal = $fetchVillain['PaypalEmail'];

        $itemname = "Item Number: $row[itemnum] -- $row[itemtype] -- $mensshirt $waistsize $w $lengthsize $l $ladystopsize $ladysdresssize $ladysbottomsize $shoesize -- $row[itemcolor]";
        $discprice = $row['DiscountedPrice'];
        $state = mysql_query("SELECT state from users WHERE Username = '$username'");
        $fetchstate = mysql_fetch_assoc($state);
        $state = $fetchstate['state'];

        switch ($storetbl) {
            case "nordstromlisting":
                $shipping = 8;
                if ($state == 'AZ' || 'CA' || 'CO' || 'CT' || 'FL' || 'GA' || 'HI' || 'IA' || 'ID' || 'IL' || 'IN' || 'KS' || 'MA' || 'MD' || 'MN' || 'MO' || 'NC' || 'NJ' || 'NV' || 'NY' || 'OH' || 'PA' || 'RI' || 'SD' || 'TX' || 'UT' || 'VA' || 'WA') {
                    $tax = $discprice * .09;
                }
                else {
                    $tax = $discprice * .02;
                }
                break;
            case "saksfifthavenuelisting":
                switch ($discprice) {
                    case ($discprice <= 25):
                        $shipping = 5;
                        break;
                    case ($discprice > 25 && $discprice <= 50):
                        $shipping = 8;
                        break;
                    case ($discprice > 50 && $discprice <= 100):
                        $shipping = 10;
                        break;
                    case ($discprice > 100 && $discprice <= 200):
                        $shipping = 13;
                        break;
                    case ($discprice > 200 && $discprice <= 300):
                        $shipping = 15;
                        break;
                    case ($discprice > 300 && $discprice <= 500):
                        $shippig = 17;
                        break;
                    case ($discprice > 500):
                        $shipping = 20;
                        break;
                }
                if ($state == 'AL' || 'AZ' || 'CA' || 'CO' || 'CT' || 'FL' || 'GA' || 'IL' || 'IN' || 'LA' || 'MA' || 'MD' || 'MN' || 'MO' || 'NC' || 'NJ' || 'NV' || 'NY' || 'OH' || 'OK' || 'PA' || 'SC' || 'TX' || 'VA' || 'DC') {
                    $tax = $discprice * .09;
                }
                else {
                    $tax = $discprice * .02;
                }
                break;
            case "neimanmarcuslisting":
                switch ($discprice) {
                    case ($discprice <= 25):
                        $shipping = 6;
                        break;
                    case ($discprice > 25 && $discprice <= 50):
                        $shipping = 9;
                        break;
                    case ($discprice > 50 && $discprice <= 100):
                        $shipping = 11.50;
                        break;
                    case ($discprice > 100 && $discprice <= 200):
                        $shipping = 16.50;
                        break;
                    case ($discprice > 200 && $discprice <= 300):
                        $shipping = 18.50;
                        break;
                    case ($discprice > 300 && $discprice <= 500):
                        $shippig = 21.50;
                        break;
                    case ($discprice > 500 && $discprice <= 700):
                        $shipping = 25.50;
                        break;
                    case ($discprice > 700 && $discprice <= 1000):
                        $shipping = 29.00;
                        break;
                    case ($discprice > 1000):
                        $shipping = 32.00;
                        break;
                }
                if ($state == 'AZ' || 'CA' || 'CO' || 'FL' || 'GA' || 'HI' || 'IL' || 'MA' || 'MD' || 'MI' || 'MN' || 'MO' || 'NC' || 'NJ' || 'NV' || 'NY' || 'PA' || 'TX' || 'VA' || 'WA' || 'DC') {
                    $tax = $discprice * .09;
                }
                else {
                    $tax = $discprice * .02;
                }   
                break;
            case "urbanoutfitterslisting":
                switch ($discprice) {
                    case ($discprice <= 50):
                        $shipping = 6;
                        break;
                    case ($discprice > 25 && $discprice < 50):
                        $shipping = 8;
                        break;
                    case ($discprice >= 50 && $discprice < 100):
                        $shipping = 10;
                        break;
                    case ($discprice >= 100 && $discprice < 150):
                        $shipping = 12;
                        break;
                    case ($discprice > 150):
                        $shipping = 0;
                        break;
                }
                if ($state == 'AL' || 'AZ' || 'CA' || 'CO' || 'CT' || 'FL' || 'GA' || 'IL' || 'IN' || 'KS' || 'LA' || 'MA' || 'MD' || 'MI' || 'MN' || 'MO' || 'NB' || 'NM' || 'NC' || 'OH' || 'OR' || 'NV' || 'NY' || 'PA' || 'RI' || 'SC' || 'TN' || 'TX' || 'UT' || 'VA' || 'VT' || 'WA' || 'WI' || 'DC') {
                    $tax = $discprice * .09;
                }
                else {
                    $tax = $discprice * .02;
                }
                break;
            case "gnclisting":
                $shipping = 6;
                break;
            case "bananarepubliclisting";
                $shipping = 7;
                //call Banana Republic for list of taxable states
                break;
            case "guesslisting":
                $shipping = 7.95;
                if ($state == 'AZ' || 'CA' || 'CO' || 'CT' || 'FL' || 'GA' || 'HI' || 'IL' || 'IN' || 'KS' || 'LA' || 'MA' || 'MD' || 'MI' || 'MN' || 'MO' || 'NJ' || 'NV' || 'NY' || 'NC' || 'OH' || 'PA' || 'RI' || 'SC' || 'TN' || 'TX' || 'VA' || 'WA') {
                    $tax = $discprice * .09;
                }
                else {
                    $tax = $discprice * .02;
                }
                break;
            case "footlockerlisting";
                $shipping = 6.99;
                if ($state == 'AK' || 'DE'|| 'MT' || 'NH' || 'OR') {
                    $tax = $discprice * .02;
                }
                else {
                    $tax = $discprice * .09;
                }
                break;
            case "americaneaglelisting":
                switch($discprice) {
                    case ($discprice < 100):
                    $shipping = 7;
                    break;
                    case ($discprice > 100):
                    $shipping = 0;
                    break;
                }
                    $tax = $discprice * .09;
                break;
        }

        echo "Status: Claimed!"?>
        <form action='https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr' target='blank' method='post'> 
        <input type='hidden' name='business' value='<?php echo $VillainPaypal ?>'> 
        <input type='hidden' name='cmd' value='_xclick'> 
        <input type='hidden' name='item_name' value="<?php echo $itemname ?>"> 
        <input type='hidden' name='shipping' value="<?php echo $shipping ?>"> 
        <input type='hidden' name='tax' value="<?php echo $tax ?>"> 
        <input type='hidden' name='amount' value='<?php echo $row['DiscountedPrice'] ?>'> 
        <input type='hidden' name='currency_code' value='USD'> 
        <input type='image' name='submit' border='0' 
        src='https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif' 
        alt='PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online'> 
        <img alt='blahblah' border='0' width='1' height='1' 
        src='https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif' > 
        </form>
        <br />
        <?php ;
```

//STATUS
}
        ?> 
            
            ">
            ">

```
    <?php

    echo "</span></div>";

    $mensshirt = "";
    $waistsize = "";
    $lengthsize = "";
    $ladystopsize = "";
    $ladysdresssize = "";
    $ladysbottomsize = "";
    $shoesize = "";
    $storename = "";
    $storetbl = "";
```

}

Comment: You've posted 300+ lines of code there. At least show you've *tried* by just posting the fragment which is puzzling you.

Comment: Please fix up your code a bit; all code needs to be indented by at least four spaces.

Comment: I can't seem to find out why do you need the loop if the index is not used in the code at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is the second time through the loop,

$storetbl is either being set to nothing at all, or a tablename that doesn't exist in the database.

"DELETE FROM $storetbl WHERE $time - datecreated >= 432000" then evaluates to something like

DELETE FROM WHERE $time - datecreated >= 432000

try some debugging statements or a debugger to determine what $storetbl is evaluated to the second time through the loop.

Comment: That's right. If none of your conditions are true, then $storetbl will be blank and the SQL query will fail. You might like to put if($storetbl == "") continue; before your query.

Comment: you might want to also initialise $storetbl/$storename at the beginning of each pass of the loop, otherwise the values from the previous pass will persist

Comment: he actually does that at the end of each loop iteration, though it's though to tell from the formatting.